# Finding a word with condition in a vector with regex on R (perl)

Tags: r, regex

I would like to find the rows in a vector with the word 'RT' in it or 'R' but not if the word 'RT' is preceded by 'no'.

The word RT may be preceded by nothing, a space, a dot, etc.
With the regex, I tried :

```
grep("(?<=[no] )RT", aaa,ignore.case = FALSE, perl = T)
```

Which was giving me all the rows with "no RT".

and

```
grep("(?=[^no].*)RT",aaa , perl = T)
```

which was giving me all the rows containing 'RT' with and without 'no' at the beginning.

What is my mistake? I thought the `^` was giving everything but the character that follows it.

Example :

```
aaa = c("RT alone", "no RT", "CT/RT", "adj.RTx", "RT/CT", "lang, RT+","npo RT" )
```

Comment: I think you wanted a negative lookbehind, `"(?<!no )RT"`. Or, if you need to check for a whole word `no`, `"(?<!\\bno )RT"`

Comment: Thanks !! It's working :-) I thought that "?<=" was meaning "there is before the string".

Comment: Correct. `(?<=...)` will go on matching the pattern only when the lookbehind pattern matches the string immediately to the left of the current location.

Comment: How would you be your solution if only R, @Wiktor?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to translate for me "(?<!no )RT" ? I may do a try : "?>"  somewhere before the word "!no " "you don't want to find "no and a space". The character (!) is a negation for all the characters that follow it.

Comment: See my answer below. Is it still unclear?

Comment: @FloraJonas, please add a full example of the string you are dealing with to be more clear. (In the question)

Comment: @Rafael The code is in the OP. It uses base R.

Comment: [snipped without T](https://regex101.com/r/YuBnax/3) *with the word 'RT' in it on R but not if the word 'RT'*, without the T is an option? I'm slightly confused. Because if so, then the ? at the end fixes. Not clear to me if necessary or not: `(?<!\bno )RT?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(?<=[no] )RT` matches any `RT` that is immediately preceded with `"n "` or `"o "`.

You should use a negative lookbehind,

```
"(?<!no )RT"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YuBnax/1).

Or, if you need to check for a whole word `no`,

```
"(?<!\\bno )RT"
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YuBnax/2).

Here, `(?<!no )` makes sure there is no `no`  immediately to the left of the current location, and only then `RT` is consumed.

Comment: I understood ! Thanks a lot. I thought that (?<=) meant "at the left of the expresion". But in fact, (?<) means "at the left of the expression", and  then (?<=) means "at the left of the expression, I will find" and  (?<!) means "at the left of the expression, I won't find"

Comment: @FloraJonas Yes, but you already know the difference, and you will be able to adjust the pattern as required later, I hope.

Comment: Little comment :  on my example (aaa) above, "(?<!no )RT" and  "(?<!\\bno )RT" are giving the same result. But  "(?<!\\bn\bo )RT" also remove "npo RT".

Comment: @FloraJonas `\b` is a word boundary, and there is no word boundary between `n`  and `o`. `n\bo` is a pattern that will never match any string.

Comment: Oups ! I think I need more training on regex...The good solution to select   "npo RT" was "(?<![no] )RT"